# Return all month names in chronological order instead of alphabetical

Tags: sql-server

I have a date field (e.g log date of a ticket), which has all the ticket created dates. I want to display all the month names in order (i.e. January, February, March...)

The log date format is `2011-08-09 10:13:000`. I can use `DateName(Month,(Log_Date))` which will give the name of the month.

When I use the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT DateName(Month,(Log_Date)) FROM TABLE_NAME 
ORDER BY DateName(Month(Log_Date))
```

It shows April, August, ... but I want to display January, February, March, ...

Answer (score 3):

Order By

```
SELECT DISTINCT Datename(month,(Log_Date)), month(Log_Date) 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
ORDER BY month(Log_Date)
```

So you are ordering by the month's numerical representation, not the name.

OR Alternatively selecting only the month's name:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempMonth
( 
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #tempMonth

SELECT DISTINCT month(ACT_CustSince) as id, DATENAME(month, ACT_CustSince) as name
FROM tblAccounts
ORDER BY month(ACT_CustSince)


SELECT name
FROM #tempMonth

DROP table #tempMonth
```

Comment: Hi Joey,Thanks for your reply... but when i tried this it is giving the following error : ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: Yes it is working fine now. Thanks a lot for your reply... Is there any way to display only one column ( Datename(month,(Log_Date))) to get the same result.